# upload multiple image to sqlserver using json mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, json

I am needing to insert a set of information in the database sqlserver data, but along with them some pictures along with some string. I am wanting to move everything by Json.

below is the input to select the image

```
   <th>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="legendaFoto5">Legenda</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="legendaFoto5" placeholder="Legenda da    Foto">
      </div>
  </th>
```

and below this the part where I pass along to Json, not this going well until I changed the first "sfoto1InputFile" to be able to upload, but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#salvarLevantamentoFicha").click(function (evt) {
            var sfoto1InputFile = $("#foto1InputFile").get(0).files[0];
            var sfoto2InputFile = $("#foto2InputFile").image;
            var sfoto3InputFile = $("#foto3InputFile").image;
            var sfoto4InputFile = $("#foto4InputFile").image;
            var sfoto5InputFile = $("#foto5InputFile").image;

            var strlegendaFoto1 = $("#legendaFoto1").val();
            var strlegendaFoto2 = $("#legendaFoto2").val();
            var strlegendaFoto3 = $("#legendaFoto3").val();
            var strlegendaFoto4 = $("#legendaFoto4").val();
            var strlegendaFoto5 = $("#legendaFoto5").val();
          $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/CadLevantamentoAmbiental/SalvarFichaLevantamentoTC")", {
                _sfoto1InputFile: sfoto1InputFile,
                _sfoto2InputFile: sfoto2InputFile,
                _sfoto3InputFile: sfoto3InputFile,
                _sfoto4InputFile: sfoto4InputFile,
                _sfoto5InputFile: sfoto5InputFile,
                _strlegendaFoto1: strlegendaFoto1,
                _strlegendaFoto2: strlegendaFoto2,
                _strlegendaFoto3: strlegendaFoto3,
                _strlegendaFoto4: strlegendaFoto4,
                _strlegendaFoto5: strlegendaFoto5                
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that ypu must take into account, and several differences between browsers. So the best that you can do is to use and existing jQuery plugin to get this done, for example:

- [jQuery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)
- [malsup jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload)

The second one is a more general solution, to post a whole form including the file uploads that it contains.

If you try to do it by yourself, without using a plugin, you'll get into big trouble.